# How to add white spaces in HTML paragraph

Tags: html

I want to do something like that

< p >

This is question 1-------------------(1)

This is question 2-------------------(2)

< / p >

but replace the dashes with spaces how can I do that.

Comment: Try &nbsp; to add white space.

Comment: Why are you doing this this way? You should use CSS for formatting, margins, spacing, etc. Also it looks like you want a list, which uses `<ul>/<ol>` and `<li>`. Why are there dashes in the first place if you don't want them?

Comment: @WesleyMurch The dashes are there to explain where and how he wants to add spaces. Sometimes I get impressed with the difficulty administrators here have to interpret the simplest sentences. What do you people mean with "not a real question"? I found it googling for "html5 insert empty space" (first result, btw), and found two useful answers.

Comment: There's also `&ensp;` and `&emsp;`, which insert bigger spaces.

Comment: This question has a lot of views and is closed to new answers. However, there is now another alternative: use `white-space: pre;` for your `p` tag; any white-space will be preserved. Check [the support](https://caniuse.com/#search=white-space%3A%20pre) first to make sure it meets any requirements you may have

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can be done easily and cleanly with `float`.

Demo: [**jsfiddle.net/KcdpW**](http://jsfiddle.net/KcdpW/)

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1 <span class="right">(1)</span></li>
    <li>Item 2 <span class="right">(2)</span></li>
</ul>​
```

**CSS:**

```
ul {
    width: 10em
}
.right {
    float: right
}​
```

Answer (score 30):

You can try it by adding `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 11):

If you really need then you can use i.e. `&nbsp;` entity to do that, but remember that fonts used to render your page are usually proportional, so "aligning" with spaces does not really work and looks ugly.